# FirebaseMessagingService does not receive notifications

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried to add push notifications to my app via FirebaseMessagingService, however, it seems like the server itself is not working.

This is the code of sending a notification function:

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody){
        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class).sendMessage(
                Constants.getRemoteMsgHeaders(),
                messageBody
        ).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    try{
                        if (response.body() !=null){
                            JSONObject responseJson  = new JSONObject(response.body());
                            JSONArray result = responseJson.getJSONArray("results");
                            if(responseJson.getInt("failure")==1){
                                JSONObject error =  (JSONObject) result.get(0);
                                makeToast(error.getString("error"));
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e){
                        makeToast(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    makeToast("notification sent");
                }
                    else{
                        makeToast("error "+response.code());

                }

            }
```

This is the code of service:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService";
    private PreferencesManager preferencesManager;

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.d("FCM", "token: " + token);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived( RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        showNotification(message.getData().get("message"));
        Log.d("FCM", "message: " + message.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.d(TAG, "received");


        User user = new User();
        user.id = message.getData().get(Constants.KEY_USER_ID);
        if(user.id!=null){
            Log.d(TAG, "received user id: " + user.id);
        }
        else{
            Log.d(TAG, "null user id");
        }
        user.name = message.getData().get(Constants.KEY_NAME);
        user.token = message.getData().get(Constants.KEY_FCM_TOKEN);
        showNotification(user.name, "aea");
        int notificationId = new Random().nextInt();
        String channel_id = "chat_message";
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_USER, user);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
        builder.setContentTitle(user.name);
        builder.setContentText(message.getData().get(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE));
        builder.setStyle(
                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(
                        message.getData().get(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE)
                )
        );
        builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence channelName = "Chat Messages";
            String channelDescription = "This Channel is used for chat message notifications";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channel_id, channelName, importance);
            channel.setDescription(channelDescription);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
        
    }
```

This is a part of my Manifest

```
        <service
            android:name=".activities.main_activities.MessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
          </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

As you can see, the Service code contains Logs, but none of them were called, hence, I think that the Service is not working at all.

However, when I call the sendNotification function from another device I always get the following Log.

24505-13086 AlarmManager            com.google.android.gms.persistent    I  setExactAndAllowWhileIdle [name: FcmRetry type: 2 triggerAtMillis: 2525414375]

I tried to google the information and read the documentation, but, unfortunately, I was not able to find the reason of this error. If you happen to possess any useful links, please, feel free to share.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).